# How to access a Gridview in Webservice file

Tags: c#, gridview, interface

If I have a gridview being used in a Default.aspx file, how do I access that gridview in the WebService.cs file? I've been experimenting with interfaces and public classes but I honestly don't know if I'm even on the right track.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

Presumably "webservice.cs" is code for some web service called via AJAX from the page. In this case there is no way to access any controls from the page (including gridview) as this information is not sent to the service.

You can either move code to full page postback (i.e. call same method server side directly) or pass all necessary information to the service.

Comment: Ok. Is it possible to pass just a string?

Comment: @anesthetic indeed. You may want search for some basic info on calling webservices.